# Why doesn't type hinting improve performance in this function?

Tags: performance, clojure, type-hinting

Here is the code:

```
(defn first-char-of-either [^String a  ^String b]
  (.substring (or a b) 0 1))
(defn first-char-of-either1 [^String a  ^String b]
  (.substring ^String (or a b) 0 1))
(time (dorun (repeatedly 1000000 #(first-char-of-either  nil "abcde"))))
(time (dorun (repeatedly 1000000 #(first-char-of-either1 nil "abcde"))))
```

The type hint in this case does not improve performance at all, why?

Comment: Not sure but maybe because `substring` is a `java.lang.String` method, and thus compiler can already know it is a string?

Comment: The compiler can't guarantee what Classes and methods might exist at runtime, so it can't know that `substring` is a method that only exists for String.

Answer (score 7):

Type hinting improves run-time performance only where the Clojure compiler fails to infer types. In the `first-char-of-either` function, `or` of the `(or a b)` expression is a macro and it is expanded to like this.

```
(let* [or__3975__auto__ a] (if or__3975__auto__ or__3975__auto__ b))
```

Because the Clojure compiler knows that both `a` and `b` have type `String`, it can infer the result type of `(or a b)` without extra type hinting to `(or a b)`.

To summarize, you do not have to add type hinting where the Clojure compiler can infer types. You can check whether the Clojure compiler can successfully infer types or not by turning `*warn-on-reflection*` on.